# How to access Gitlab CI/CD variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I don't think this was asked before, but correct me if it was!

I am using a gitlab CI/CD pipeline to build and push my docker images using kaniko. My system works with gpt and I have the api key in the CI/CD variables. I also use a .env file with many other variables that can be publicly accessible/seen. My task is like this:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - export GPT_KEY=$GPT_API_KEY
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "backend"
      --dockerfile "backend/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_NAME_BACKEND}:0.0.1"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_NAME_BACKEND}:latest"
```

(I want to add the tag rule only after I got it to work)
And then I access my key like this:

```py
class GptInterface:

    load_dotenv()

    GPT_URL = None
    GPT_KEY = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.GPT_URL = os.environ.get('GPT_URL')
        self.GPT_KEY = os.environ.get('GPT_KEY')

    def some_function(self):
        print(f"dummy example: {self.GPT_KEY}")
```

However, the GPT key is not read out. The push itself works. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variables as `build-arg` to the dockerfile and make them environment variables for the container.

Define the variables inside the dockerfile:

```
FROM some_image:latest

ARG GPT_URL
ARG GPT_KEY

ENV GPT_URL=$GPT_URL
ENV GPT_KEY=$GPT_KEY

# ...
```

Then you can pass the variables during the docker build process:

```yaml
build:
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "backend"
      --dockerfile "backend/Dockerfile"
      --build-arg GPT_URL=$GPT_URL
      --build-arg GPT_KEY=$GPT_API_KEY
```